# Regular expression for extracting information

Tags: java, regex

I have a csv file with the following data format

```
123,"12.5","0.6","15/9/2012 12:11:19"
```

These numbers are:

- order number
- price
- discount rate
- date and time of sale

I want to extract these data from the line.

I have tried the regular expression:

```
String line = "123,\"12.5\",\"0.6\",\"15/9/2012 12:11:19\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\W?),\"([\\d\\.\\-]?)\",\"([\\d\\.\\-]?)\",\"([\\W\\-\\:]?)\"");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
if(scanner.hasNext(pattern)) {
    ...
}else{
    // Alaways goes to here
}
```

It looks like my pattern is not correct as it always goes to the else section. What did I do wrong? Can someone suggests a solution for this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried splitting on comma and stripping the double quotes instead?

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bit overcomplicated to specifically split, you should try splitting by the most obvious common delimiter between the elements, which is a comma. Perhaps you should try something like this:

```
    final String info = "123,\"12.5\",\"0.6\",\"15/9/2012 12:11:19\"";
    final String[] split = info.split(",");
    final int orderNumber = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
    final double price = Double.parseDouble(split[1].replace("\"", ""));
    final double discountRate = Double.parseDouble(split[2].replace("\"", ""));
    final String date = split[3].replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: This is a correct alternative, but not what the OP is asking. The OP is asking why his regex fails and a possible solution.

Comment: @FèlixGalindoAllué His RegEx is failing because he is trying to overcomplicate whatever it is he is trying to accomplish. If I were to correct the RegEx, it would only promote this "abuse" of using such specific and particular RegEx for something as simple as this. Also, I am answering the OP's question: "Can someone suggests a solution for this?"

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are very cumbersome for this type of work.

I suggest using a CSV library such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) instead.

The library can parse the `String` entries into a `String` array and individual entries can be parsed as required. Here an OpenCSV example for the specific problem:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
   int orderNumber = Integer.parseInt(nextLine[0]);
   double price = Double.parseDouble(nextLine[1]);
   double discountRate = Double.parseDouble(nextLine[2]);
   ...
}
```

Full documentation and examples can be found [here](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read)

Answer (score 0):

`?` in regex means "zero or one occurrence". You probably wanted to use `+` instead (one or more) so it could capture all the digits, points, colons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`scanner.hasNext(pattern)`

from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29)

> Returns true if the next complete token matches the specified pattern.

but next token is `123,"12.5","0.6","15/9/2012` because scanner tokenizes words using space.

Also there are few problems with your regex

- you used `?` which means **zero or one** where you should use `*` - zero or more, or `+` - one or more,
- you used `\\W` at start but this will also exclude numbers.

---

If you really want to use scanner and regex then try with

```
Pattern.compile("(\\d+),\"([^\"]+)\",\"([^\"]+)\",\"([^\"]+)\"");
```

and change used delimiter to new line mark with

```
scanner.useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution to your situation:

```
    String line = "123,\"12.5\",\"0.6\",\"15/9/2012 12:11:19\"";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+),\\\"([0-9.]+)\\\",\\\"([0-9.]+)\\\",\\\"([0-9/:\\s]+)\\\"");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
    scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
    if(scanner.hasNext(pattern)) {
        MatchResult result = scanner.match();
        System.out.println("1st: " + result.group(1));
        System.out.println("2nd: " + result.group(2));
        System.out.println("3rd: " + result.group(3));
        System.out.println("4th: " + result.group(4));
    }else{
        System.out.println("There");
    }
```

Note that `?` means 0 or 1 occurrences, meanwhile `+` means 1 or more.

Observe the use of `0-9` for digits. You can also use `\d`if you like. For spaces, you must change the delimiter of the scanner with `scanner.useDelimiter("\n")`, for example.

The output of this snippet is:

```
1st: 123
2nd: 12.5
3rd: 0.6
4th: 15/9/2012 12:11:19
```